# Data is not displayed from the array on page load

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have made an array which stores the data of the items from my API and tried displaying it in my page.

But the items are not loading on the page.

the array which has the items is this

```
const allCategory = ["All",...new Set(filteredData.map((curElem)=> {return curElem.Category}))];
```

In this way I'm displaying the items from the array:

```
 const [catItems, setCatItems] = useState(allCategory);


    const filterItem = (category) =>{

        if(category === "All"){
            setData(mainArray);
            return;
        }

        const updatedItems = mainArray.filter((curElem)=>{
            return curElem.Category === category;
        })
        setData(updatedItems);
    }
```

```
<div>
{
 catItems.map((curClem, index)=>{
    return <li key={index} onClick={() => filterItem(curClem)}>{curClem}</li>
                        })
                    }
</div>
```

When I tried loading the array in use effect and the complete page goes blank :

```
useEffect(() => {
        async function fetchData(){
          try {
            const response = await fetch('https://63b6952d1907f863aafa9342.mockapi.io/menu/')
            const data = await response.json();
            setData(data);
            setMainArray(data);
            setCatItems(data);
          } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
          }
        }
    
        fetchData();
      }, []);
```

I think I'm making a mistake while loading the array in use effect.

Tell me what is the issue I'm facing or the error I made in my code and help me with solving it.

My data from array is not displayed on page and I tried calling them in use Effect but it is not working. I think I'm making a mistake in calling the set state in use Effect.

I'm providing the sandbox link for further details in my code:

https://codesandbox.io/s/qr-menu-smvr6h?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Can you [edit] the post to include a more complete and comprehensive [mcve]? As it is written it is difficult to see where the variables are declared and what values they may have. Is there an actual error? If so, please include error details and any code stacktraces.

Comment: I have added my sandbox link can you look into it @Drew Reese

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`allCategories` is what is considered derived state. It's derived from the current `data` state and the `vegOnly` state. The `data` state is fetched on the initial render and updated ***after*** the initial render, so it can't be used to compute the initial `catItems` state.

Derived state doesn't belong in React state, since it's easily derived from other existing state/props/etc. This means the UI should directly reference the computed `allCategory` array.

```
...

const [data, setData] = useState([]);
const [vegOnly, setVegOnly] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => {
  async function fetchData() {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(
        "https://63b6952d1907f863aafa9342.mockapi.io/menu/"
      );
      const data = await response.json();
      setData(data);
      setMainArray(data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  }

  fetchData();
}, []);

...

const filteredData =
  vegOnly === false ? data : data.filter((item) => item.Type === "veg"); 
  //from above to here for filter veg only

const allCategory = [
  "All",
  ...new Set(filteredData.map((curElem) => curElem.Category))
]; // 3rd step to make it array
```

...

```
<ul>
  {allCategory.map((curClem, index) => {
    return (
      <li key={index} onClick={() => filterItem(curClem)}>
        {curClem}
      </li>
    );
  })}
</ul>
```

There's a fair amount of redundant/unnecessary state. All the "filtered data" also considered derived state. You should store once copy of the data array in state, and the filtering conditions, not duplicates of the array.

Example:

```
const App = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]); //solved from stackoverflow
  const [search, setSearch] = useState("");
  const [category, setCategory] = useState("All");
  const [vegOnly, setVegOnly] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
      try {
        const response = await fetch(
          "https://63b6952d1907f863aafa9342.mockapi.io/menu/"
        );
        const data = await response.json();
        setData(data);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
      }
    }

    fetchData();
  }, []);

  const handleVegInputChange = (e) => {
    const { checked } = e.target;
    setVegOnly(checked);
  };

  // filter the data inline by the different filtering conditons
  // and selected category.
  const filteredData = data
    .filter((item) => {
      return item.Name.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase());
    })
    .filter((item) => {
      if (vegOnly) {
        return item.Type === "veg";
      }
      return true;
    })
    .filter((item) => {
      if (category !== "All") {
        return item.Category === category;
      }
      return true;
    });

  // Derive the categories from the data array
  const allCategory = [
    "All",
    ...new Set(data.map((curElem) => curElem.Category))
  ]; // 3rd step to make it array

  // Set the selected filtering category
  const filterItem = (category) => {
    setCategory(category);
  };

  return (
    <div className="first">
      ...
      ...
      <div className="resinfo2">
        <div className="rescategory">
          <ul>
            {allCategory.map((curClem, index) => {
              return (
                <li
                  key={index}
                  // Style the selected category
                  style={{
                    color: curClem === category ? "lightgreen" : "inherit"
                  }}
                  onClick={() => filterItem(curClem)}
                >
                  {curClem}
                </li>
              );
            })}
          </ul>
        </div>

        <div className="resitems">
          <div className="box">
            <input
              type="text"
              className="search-input"
              placeholder="Search for dishes"
              value={search}
              onChange={(e) => setSearch(e.target.value)}
            />
            <img src="/images/search.png" />
          </div>

          <div className="contents">
            {data ? (
              <div>
                <div className="checkbox">
                  <label>
                    <input
                      type="checkbox"
                      value={vegOnly}
                      onChange={handleVegInputChange}
                    />
                    Veg Only
                  </label>
                </div>
                <div className="items">
                  {filteredData.map((item) => (
                    <div className="itemslist" key={item.id}>
                      <ul>
                        <li
                          className={
                            item.Type === "veg" ? "veg" : "non-veg"
                          }
                        ></li>
                        <li>{item.Name}</li>
                        <li>₹ {item.Price}</li>
                        <img src="/images/pizza1.jpg" />
                        <div className="hr"></div>
                      </ul>
                    </div>
                  ))}
                </div>
              </div>
            ) : (
              <div className="loading">Loading...</div>
            )}
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="rescart"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

[image: Edit data-is-not-displayed-from-the-array-on-page-load]

Comment: What about the side menu it is only showing the active category and all others are disappearing and appear after all is active. Is there a way to keep all of them visible

Comment: @oneforall1 Sorry, the UI/CSS in the sandbox you linked is pretty busted. What is the side menu? Are you talking about the categories (*`allCategory`*) that are now rendered? It looks like your code filters all but the selected category. If the intended behavior is to only highlight the selected category then you'll want to save the selected category and conditionally apply a classname or style instead of filtering out all the non-selected categories.

Comment: I have updated the code based on your suggestion and if you are looking for the side menu CSS it's from line 104.

Comment: Last one issue left out can you look into it. Once look in the sandbox that if one category is active all other are disappeared. Is there anything you can do to it.

Comment: @oneforall1 filtered data is also generally considered derived "state". Which "data" array is the absolute source of truth of the data you want to render all the UI from?

Comment: @oneforall1 I've forked and updated your sandbox. Check my answer update.

Comment: thanks for the solution it worked and I'm going through your changes to learn something new :)

Comment: I was not sure about the task so I removed the post.

Comment: @oneforall1 Sorry I hadn't responded back on your other post. Is that one a school or work assignment? If so then it's probably best to ask the assigner to clarify what exactly the task is they want you to do.